# Popular browsers on the Mac

Tags: macos, browser, safari

Are there any other popular browsers used on the Mac besides Safari? For Windows, there are significant numbers of users with FF and Chrome, but is this also true for Mac users? Or am I safe to say that Safari covers 95% of Mac users?
I am asking so that I know what browser/platform combinations I need to test for my application.

Comment: I think eventhough safari is very popular amongst Mac users , you could still use chrome,FF,opera for your testing purposes.

Comment: Duplicate of http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22455/is-it-possible-to-get-browser-marketshare-by-os - which got migrated from StackOverflow last year...

Comment: Here is the answer: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-popular-web-browser-among-Mac-OS-X-users-Are-there-any-usage-stats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We find that Chrome and Firefox are still fairly common on Macs but about 10-20% of Mac users depending on the site.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any experience with the performance of Chrome and FireFox on Macs? If you have tested FF and Chrome on a PC, is it safe to say that your app would also work on these browsers on a Mac?

Comment: It's rare to find any major differences, usually fonts are the only real issue we have

Answer (score 1):

I'd definetely not assume that you shouldn't need to test for mac ff and chrome. This will not be a very large amount of work, since the mac chrome or ff does not seem to vary a lot with their respective Windows versions.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is available for Mac, as well as Opera. Google Chrome (Chromium) is there too.
Here's a list of available browsers for Mac:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mac_OS_X_web_browsers

Keep other platforms in mind when testing as well. E.g. Konqueror is very popular on Linux.