# Which browser is most popular on MacOS ? (OSX…)

Tags: macos, testing, browser, compatibility, web-statistics

I would like to determine which is the most popular browser for OSX, and what the percentages are. I know the 3 most popular browser are most likely Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. I would like to know (roughly) the usage statistics for each browser FOR OSX ONLY. This doesn't seem to be as easy to find as I thought it would be.

Several articles I have read have pointed to sites such as: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp). However w3schools (I know they have statistics that shouldn't be trusted but I am just using it as an example since it shows near the top of the Google search), and other sites I have tried, simply show overall usage, not usage by browser, which is what I am looking for.

Even articles on Stack Exchange that I have read do not provide a clear answer:
[Popular browsers on the Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192041/popular-browsers-on-the-mac) & [is it possible to get browser marketshare by OS?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22455/is-it-possible-to-get-browser-marketshare-by-os) ...

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why has this been closed for being opinion based? Statistics on browser usage don't seem to be opinions?

Comment: This is not an opinion question (what's your favorite browser). This is a factual question (how do we determine browser usage by OS). And it's a good question. Web developers need these statistics to make informed decisions on where to focus their efforts.

Comment: The answer is here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-popular-web-browser-among-Mac-OS-X-users-Are-there-any-usage-stats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally over a week later, I found a rough answer to my question, in case it helps anyone else out.

I found a CNET article dated Sept 26, 2012 which states:

"Safari... is used by 85 percent of the folks running that operating system. Chrome... took 3 percent of the iOS market. All other browsers, including Dolphin and Atomic, combined for 11.9 percent share."

[CNET article](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1035_3-57520547-94/safari-on-ios-favored-among-85-percent-of-users/)

Comment: Note that the article is talking about Safari on iOS (iPhones and iPads), which is totally unrelated to the share on Mac OS X.

Comment: More current answer is here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-popular-web-browser-among-Mac-OS-X-users-Are-there-any-usage-stats